# TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined in my api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I try to create a user without a address or change the password in my api   and it returns: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined"

here is my code :

```
 UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next){
     const code = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
     console.log(this.address)
     console.log(code)
    
     if(Array.isArray(code)&&code[0]){
             this.latitude = code[0].latitude
             this.longitude = code[0].longitude
}
```

I already tried:

```
 UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next){
     
     if(typeof address !== null){
           const code = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
           console.log(this.address)
           console.log(code)
          if(Array.isArray(code)&&code[0]){
                  this.latitude = code[0].latitude
                  this.longitude = code[0].longitude
  }}
```

but when I fix the error with

```
 if(typeof address !== 'undefined')
```

it simply dont geocode

Comment: Your code is unable to access `this`. Essentially, you want to pass through the variable you think your accessing when you use `this` another way.

Comment: Is it MongoDB/mongoose?